# JavaX Activation Cannot Be Resolved

Tags: java, javax.activation

By following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_inlineimage_in_email.htm) example, I got the following inline message in Eclipse Java Oxygen.

```
"The import javax.activation cannot be resolved"
```

Documentation for JavaMail says this object is in JAF or moved into `jakarta.activation` but I don't understand how to fix that, or if the example is too deprecated, or my environment needs to be fixed, or all the previous...

Somebody has a functional example?

Comment: Do you have required jar in your classpath?

Comment: I included the `javax.mail.jar` and the only error highlighted are the `import javax.activation` lines.

Comment: Are you using JDK 9 or newer?  JAF was removed from JDK 9, just add it separately from [Maven](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/jar).

Comment: JavaMail doesn't have anything to do with `javax.activation`. If you're using that you need the appropriate JAR file, and it doesn't come from JavaMail. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks. I added the `javax.activation` JAR and that solved the problem.